# Dynamic Table table javascript not working

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","destination_get.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

Please help

Comment: Please format your code first

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: Also stop calling javascript as Java .. these are two different beasts.

Answer (score 0):

The error contains all the information you need here:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Your JS thinks there is no element with `id="txtHint"` in the document, therefore `document.getElementById` returns null, and null is not an object with the property `innerHTML`.

Comment: This is code select and call java script
<h3><span class='name'>Interconect</span></h3>  
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<td><b>Customers:</b></td>

<Td>
<?php $query=mysqli_query($link,"Select id FROM destination"); ?>
<select name="billing_destination" class="form"  onchange="showUser(this.value)">

<option value="">Select Destination:</option>
<?php while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['billing_destination'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

Comment: @Andrei, you are not doing a proper use of SO. Please, read the basis before asking something. What you have posted in your comment could be in the question. We need as much information as possible to help. Anyway, I think @DanielM is right, it doesn't seem to exist any element with id `txtHint` in your html code.

Comment: @Andrei Here is a [really good guide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to get the most out of SO.